# Final step - run this script for all files in directory

Tags: bash

With 5 hours of learning and a lot of help from really smart people I have a script running perfect, but I need to scale it up. Currently I key in the filename of a single file on the third line as a variable, save the script and run it. The script processes with no problem. File is uploaded to Google CLoud Storage, Firebase is written to, all links work. Everything is great except the manual entry of the filename.

My question is how do I make this same script run for all flac files found in the directory?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/library/422980-2560-WIN
file="Date-2019-07-10__Time-16:36:50.flac"
echo $file | awk -F'-' '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}' | awk -F':' '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}' | awk -F'__' '{print $1, $2, $3}' | awk -F'.' '{print $1}' | awk -F'Time' '{print $$year=`awk -F' ' '{print $1}' awkresults.txt`
month=`awk -F' ' '{print $2}' awkresults.txt`
date=`awk -F' ' '{print $3}' awkresults.txt`
hour=`awk -F' ' '{print $4}' awkresults.txt`
minute=`awk -F' ' '{print $5}' awkresults.txt`
second=`awk -F' ' '{print $6}' awkresults.txt`

sudo gcloud ml speech recognize /var/www/html/library/422980-2560-WIN/$file --language-code='en-US' >STT.txt
STT=`grep -Po '"transcript": *\K"[^"]*"' STT.txt | cut -d '"' -f2`
sudo gsutil cp /var/www/html/library/422980-2560-WIN/$file gs://422980
sudo /usr/local/fuego --credentials /home/repeater/medialunaauth01-280236ff5e5f.json add 422980 '
        {
                "bucketObjecturl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/422980/'"$file"'",
                "fileDate":"'"$date"'",
                "fileMonth":"'"$month"'",
                "fileName": "filenametest33",
                "fileHour":"'"$hour"'",
                "fileMinute":"'"$minute"'",
                "fileSecond":"'"$second"'",
                "fileYear":"'"$year"'",
                "liveOnline": "0",
                "qCChecked": "0",
                "speechToText":"'"$STT"'",
                "transcribedData": ""
}'
sleep 1
rm $file
```

**Noted: I understand for proper creation of error free json files I should be using jq, I will learn it next - I promise.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the script to get the filename from a command line argument:

```
file=$1
```

Then loop over all the files in the directory:

```
for file in $.flac
do
    /path/to/your/script "$file"
done
```

Or you could put the loop in your script, and use the wildcard when running the script.

Your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/library/422980-2560-WIN
for file in "$@"; do
    echo $file | awk -F'-' '{print $2, $3, $4, $5}' | awk -F':' '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}' | awk -F'__' '{print $1, $2, $3}' | awk -F'.' '{print $1}' | awk -F'Time' '{print $$year=`awk -F' ' '{print $1}' awkresults.txt`
    month=`awk -F' ' '{print $2}' awkresults.txt`
    date=`awk -F' ' '{print $3}' awkresults.txt`
    hour=`awk -F' ' '{print $4}' awkresults.txt`
    minute=`awk -F' ' '{print $5}' awkresults.txt`
    second=`awk -F' ' '{print $6}' awkresults.txt`

    sudo gcloud ml speech recognize /var/www/html/library/422980-2560-WIN/$file --language-code='en-US' >STT.txt
    STT=`grep -Po '"transcript": *\K"[^"]*"' STT.txt | cut -d '"' -f2`
    sudo gsutil cp /var/www/html/library/422980-2560-WIN/$file gs://422980
    sudo /usr/local/fuego --credentials /home/repeater/medialunaauth01-280236ff5e5f.json add 422980 '
            {
                    "bucketObjecturl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/422980/'"$file"'",
                    "fileDate":"'"$date"'",
                    "fileMonth":"'"$month"'",
                    "fileName": "filenametest33",
                    "fileHour":"'"$hour"'",
                    "fileMinute":"'"$minute"'",
                    "fileSecond":"'"$second"'",
                    "fileYear":"'"$year"'",
                    "liveOnline": "0",
                    "qCChecked": "0",
                    "speechToText":"'"$STT"'",
                    "transcribedData": ""
    }'
    sleep 1
    rm $file
done
```

Then run the script as:

```
/path/to/your/script *.flac
```

Comment: Thank you... Off topic for you Barmar (since you are one of the guys suggesting it) is jq difficult to learn? I just found the man page for it. I ask if it is difficult because I am having a very tough time learning sed and awk, syntaxes are so complex with those tools, how does jq compare?

Comment: It's a little tricky, since it's a language all its own. I haven't used it much myself, I don't use `bash` for anything complicated.

Comment: You are suggesting that the change and the loop be within the same script fie as edited above, or this should be called from another script? When I do that I get the error: bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1

Comment: This is a separate script.